# Google Streetview images show as grey screen in Internet Explorer?

Tags: google-maps

I have developed a javascript API application that retrieves Google Streetview images based on where a user clicks on an interactive map.

For some reason in the past couple of days there have been intermittent issues with this process as a grey screen is just returned and it isn't until you start to pan around that an image is returned.

The same thing happens in Google's own API example here:-

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service.html

After the initial click, subsequent clicks just return a grey screen (this is in Internet Explorer 7, it appears to work in Google Chrome and Firefox).

This didn't used to be a problem - has anyone else experienced this issue when using Internet Explorer (either version 7 or another)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the 3.8 nightly api build.
Specify a specific api build.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.7&sensor=true_or_false
```

[Google documentation reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Versioning)